# After disable all the magento extension I am unable to access the site /Admin panel

Tags: php, magento, module, extension-methods, magento-1.8

I was trying to solve the error(Image type and information need to be specified for each store view) regarding product Image upload in magento admin panel.  So I had disabled all the Magento extensions via System > Configuration > Advance . But after this I am unable to access the admin panel/ Website.

How can I enable my all the extensions via server. and access the Magento Admin Panel. 
I tried to enable the extensions via server, but it's already shows "true". What I have to do. Please help.
Path: /var/www/app/etc/modules/ExtensionNaame.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Mage_Weee>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>core</codePool>
        <depends>
            <Mage_Catalog />
            <Mage_Tax />
            <Mage_Sales />
        </depends>
    </Mage_Weee>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the database you can select the production db and run the following SQL command:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data`
SET `value` = '0'
WHERE `path` LIKE 'advanced/modules_disable_output/%';
```

The % character is a wildcard value which will allow for all modules to be targeted when matching the path.

If you don't have access to the database directly you can create a php file in the root directory with the following:

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$modules = array_keys((array)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules')->children());

foreach ($modules as $module) {
    $config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config();
    $config->saveConfig('advanced/modules_disable_output/' . $module, '0', 'default', 0);
}
```

Then go run this php file. It will get a list of all modules and set the value = 0 (enabled) for scope = 'default' and scope_id = 0.

Good luck

Comment: After changing `core_config_data` values for disabling **module output**, manually clear cache by deleting all subdirectories in  `var/cache/` so Magento will re-read the settings from `core_config_data`.